# Safe temperature for CPU under constant load

Tags: cpu, temperature

I have an AMD Ryzen 3600 and decided to run BOINC on my PC when I'm not using it, the thing is, I want to contribute to the science projects but I don't want to ruin my computer in the process and the CPU can get pretty toasty when running that type of workload for an extensive period.

My plan is to use MSI Afterburner to throttle the CPU if it gets too hot but I can't find what temperature I should use for reference. Under the [specifications](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-5-3600) it's saying that the max temp for this CPU is 95 C, but from I understand, that is for short bursts of workload, right? Not really a 24/7 load. Would this temperature be enough for this type of constant load, or should I aim for something lower like 70 C or even 50 C.

Comment: 50 degrees is fine. I see that on lots of CPUs. 70 degrees is normally well within tolerance, but make sure heat sinking and cooling is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

50 degrees is fine. I see that on lots of CPUs. 70 degrees is normally well within tolerance, but make sure heat sinking and cooling is good.

Here is a good overall article:

[CPU temperatures](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000687.htm)

> Average processor temperatures under full load
>
> The majority of today's
> desktop processors should not exceed temperatures of 45-50°C when
> idle, or 80°C when under full load. Below is a chart listing many
> types of processors and their average temperatures under full load